# Right-clicking in Wasteland 2 without a mouse on OS X?

Tags: macos, mouse, wasteland-2

I can't seem to figure out how to right-click in Wasteland 2 without a mouse.

I'm playing on a Macbook Pro, and the usual trick of rightclicking (done with control-key pressed) does not work. Changing the hotkey assignment away from control did not help.

Comment: Normally within the Mac Preferences for Mouse/Trackpad you can choose to enable a right click. Is this not the case with Macbooks?

Comment: Changing the secondary click to "bottom right-hand corner" in the preferences actually worked, the default did not. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: With the assistance of future visitors in mind, I'll add this as an answer just so it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the Mac Preferences for Mouse/Trackpad you can choose to assign a 'secondary click' to the bottom right hand corner of the Trackpad.
This will however affect your full operating system and will not just affect the game.